# CSS List Question

Tags: css

I'm looking for a quick cross browser solution to my need for auto margins.

I have a simple list:

```
<ul>
     <li>text</li>
     <li>text</li>
     <li class="possibly_last">text</li>
</ul>
```

With a width of 600px.

What I need is CSS code to make sure there is an even margin between each `<li>`.

So that they stretch across the full 600px evenly.

I may need to as a "last" class, but that's fine.

I just want a browser friendly way to do this.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: "cross browser solution" - what browsers do you need to support? IE7? IE6? (please no) Also, are you talking horizontal or vertical here?

Comment: Do you mean border? Can you provide an image demonstrating what you mean?

Comment: I can probably help you, but I'm a bit unclear on what you want. Could you make a really quick sketch showing what it should look like? This is what I'm guessing: http://i.imgur.com/XxJdX.png

Comment: There's really not much point in supporting IE6 anymore... No-one uses it and those who do probably only do for testing. Stick to IE7+ In regard to meaning, I think the OP means they want a UL 600px wide, with 3 list elements displayed side by side with spacing in between them. Please see the JSFiddle in my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
}
</style>
```

If that does not work, try this:

```
<style>
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 200px; // or less
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean you don't want a margin after the last `li`? In that case, use the CSS `:last-child` selector:

```
ul li
{
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 190px;       // 190px = 200px - margin width
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

ul li:last-child
{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

**Please note that this will *NOT* work in any internet explorer except IE9. Sorry :-(**

As a fix, you could use JavaScript (notably jQuery) to edit the CSS of the last child.

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/WtLAm/2/

Comment: Actually I need a margin, I need the <li>'s to stretch across the full width.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be done with margins, I suggest you this solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/wY5t6/
css:

```
ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    width: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If you need to set padding, background etc on list item than you can do it this way:
http://jsfiddle.net/wY5t6/1/
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
    <li class="possibly_last"><span>text</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    border: 1px green dotted;
    width: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

li span {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to float the list items so they stretch horizontally to fill the ul that way? if so, something like

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    ul {width: 600px;}
    li {display: inline; float: left; width: 33%;}
</style>
```

would work.